# I want to make an oscillator with 160 MHz

Tags: rf, frequency, oscillator, modulation

I want this for my project. So I have decided to make a basic Wien bridge oscillator.

$$f = \frac{1}{2\pi R C}$$

So if I choose a capacitor of 0.1 nano farads and a resistor of 10 ohms, I should get around 160 MHz. 
Will I get the 160 MHz, I heard that a wine bridge cancels out higher frequencies.

Comment: I'd forget the Wien bridge.  (10 pF, 100 ohm.. but you still need gain of three(+)) For that type of frequency look into an LC and a transistor.

Comment: why would you change values to 10pF and 100 ohm.

Comment: 100Ω resistors are much more common than 10Ω.

Comment: @user124627, You'll want to do this with an opamp?  I figured the opmap will be happier with 100 ohms.  It's an easier impedance for the opamp to drive.  (less current requirement.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting suitable parts values is ONE problem, which - however - could be solved in this case. The bigger problem is to find a suitable operational amplifier. A Wien-type oscillator needs a gain of three - and to achieve this (without disturbing phase shifts) for a frequency of 160 MHz requires an opamp with a  gain-bandwidth product of at least several GHz. 
Therefore, I recommend to try one of the classical transistor-based oscillator topologies.

EDIT1: Another problem connected with the use of opamps is the limited **slew rate** of these devices - even if you could find an opamp with the required gan-bandwidth product.

**EDIT2:**There are some special opamp topologies which can be used for an 160MHz Wien oscillator: Current-feedback amplifiers exhibit very large gain-bandwidth products and phantastic slew rates (SR).
Example: OPA695 allows a gain of three at 160MHz with a slew rate SR=4300V/µs.

Comment: thankyou so much, I didn't know op amps have bandwidth

Comment: hey, won't a 741 op amp work

Comment: would 3volts be enough Vcc for OPA695

Comment: A 741 type certainly will NOT work for this purpose. Regarding supply voltages for the OPA695: Why didn´t you consult the data sheet?